# Ho to execute action without change current page?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, json, ajax

I want to add selected items to session in controller without change current page.

```
<form>
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Title)
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">@Model.Title</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <ul class=" check-list" id="GroupFeatures">
                @{

                    for (int i = 0; i < Model.GroupFeatures.Count; i++)
                    {
                        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.GroupFeatures[i].Id)
                        <li><span> @Model.GroupFeatures[i].Title </span> @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.GroupFeatures[i].Value, new SelectList(Model.GroupFeatures[i].Features, "Id", "Title"), new { @class = "form-control" })</li>
                    }
                }
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button id="submit" class="btn btn-default "  >ثبت</button>

        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

in script.

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function () {
var data = $('form').serialize();

$.getJSON("/store/MakeMyFavorite", data, function (data) {
    //check your data here what it is returning
    if ($.trim(data) == "favorite") {
        alert('s');
    }
});

});
```

and in controller .

```
public JsonResult MakeMyFavorite(ProductFeatureViewModel model)
    {
       string result = "favorite";
        return this.Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

but change url to `/Store?__RequestVerificationToken=526Wd9OvHI89rwGrRuCgzgDhAGloEuZkOLSdoQFTELZcLQliMMWlc8AeMn3DS4Sfy5-k8xr2tavkno-2aNBjIyJXR4c8T9PmNSs-KlUNITo1&Id=1&Title`

Comment: What do you mean by "without change current page"?

Comment: when i use this code, post back page to new url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stop the normal behaviour of the form when submitted, which is to do a full postback to the server.

For that you can use the preventDefault() function of the event which is raised by the browser:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submit', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //...etc
```